# Count how many times a variable is called

Tags: python, variables, counting

I want to add something that will count how many times a variable is used (like variable `c`) and output in number of times variable `c` was used. What functions can I use? Here's the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

question = raw_input
y = "Blah"
c = "Blahblahb"


print "Is bacon awesome"
if question() = "Yes":
    print y
else:
    print c

print "Blah"
if question() = "Yes":
    print y
else:
    print c
```

Comment: What do you consider "using"?  When it is assigned to?  Read from?  Both?  And more importantly, **why**?  This sounds like an X Y problem, tell us what you are actually trying to achieve, not what you think is the solution.

Comment: Why not use getters and setters that keep track? Easier to modify in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can try this:

```
question = raw_input
y = "Blah"
c = "Blahblahb"
y_counter = 0
c_counter = 0


print "Is bacon awesome"
if question() = "Yes":
    print y
    y_counter = y_counter + 1
else:
    print c
    c_counter = c_counter + 1

print "Blah"
if question() = "Yes":
    print y
    y_counter = y_counter + 1
else:
    print c
    c_counter = c_counter + 1

print "y was used " + str(y_counter) + " times!"
print "c was used " + str(c_counter) + " times!"
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `+=`?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a counter variable. Lets call it 'count'. Every time you print c, you increment count by 1. I've pasted the code below. You can print the count variable in the end

```
question = raw_input
y = "Blah"
c = "Blahblahb"

count=0

print "Is bacon awesome"
if question() == "Yes":
    print y
else:
    count+=1
    print c

print "Blah"
if question() == "Yes":
    print y
else:
    count+=1
    print c

print c
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this simply enough using an incrementing variable.

```
counter = 0
# Event you want to track
counter += 1
```

Your Python 2.7 code, with a counter:

```
question = raw_input
y = "Blah"
c = "Blahblahb"
counter = 0


print "Is bacon awesome"
if question() = "Yes":
    print y
else:
    print c
    counter += 1

print "Blah"
if question() = "Yes":
    print y
else:
    print c
    counter +=1

print counter
```

Comment: @user3543300 Excuse me? Since when does += not work in Python?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to increment a counter and there a many ways to do that. One way is to encapsulate in a `class` and use `property`, but this uses more advanced features of python:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.y_count = 0

    @property
    def y(self):
        self.y_count += 1
        return 'Blah'

a = A()
print(a.y)
# Blah
print(a.y)
# Blah
print(a.y)
# Blah
print(a.y_count)
# 3
```